# Count occurence of word using java

Tags: java, csv, selenium

```
Ticket Type Priority
    Assigned Incident 3 - Medium
    Acknowledgement Service Request 3 - Medium
    Assigned Problem 2 - High
    Assigned Incident 3 - Medium
    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium
    Closed Incident 3 - Medium
    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium
    Assigned Incident 2 - High
    Closed Incident 3 - Medium
    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium
    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium
    Acknowledgement Service Request 3 - Medium
    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium
    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium
    Acknowledgement Service Request 3 - Mediumc
```

I am able to get above table data from webpage using java selenium.
I want to calculate

1. No of Incident
2. No of Incident + 3 - Medium
3. No of Incident + 3 - Medium + Assigned and so on..

And store that value into csv file specific cell..

I have stored above table date in a variable.

```
public static void get_data()  {
String txt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='jtrac jtrac-    list']")).getText();
System.out.println(txt);
}
```

I have done earlier above things using powershell like this

```
$B = $A | Select-String "Incident","Problem" | measure-object; $C = $B.Count;
$obj[0].Measure = $C
```

$A contains above table data. Select-String select pattern string and measure. $obj handles Target csv file store data one by one $obj[*]

But i am not sure in Java.

Comment: What have you tried, and in what way didn't it work?

Comment: Is the table data stored in some file or are you directly storing it in a `String` variable in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is below Code. The [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object has extra methods for you to get more. Change the Pattern mentioned in method to suit your need.

```
 String myTotalString= "Ticket Type Priority\n" +
"    Assigned Incident 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Acknowledgement Service Request 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Assigned Problem 2 - High\n" +
"    Assigned Incident 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Closed Incident 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Assigned Incident 2 - High\n" +
"    Closed Incident 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Acknowledgement Service Request 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Assigned Service Request 3 - Medium\n" +
"    Acknowledgement Service Request 3 - Medium";

    private int getIncidentOrProblems()
    {
        int i = 0;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Incident|Problem");
        Matcher m = p.matcher( myTotalString );
        while (m.find()) {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: How to use multiple pattern like No of Incident + 3 - Medium + Assigned